# insert records into table where one filed is from another table

Tags: sql

i want to insert records into table "Cours_Change" but one filed is from other table "Devise";
I have selected the liste of Devises and its id will also be inserted into table "Cours_Change"

```
insert into Cours_Change (DAT_JOUR_CCHN,mont_caba_cchn,mont_cabc_cchn,mont_cvba_cchn,mont_cvbc_cchn,cod_etat_cchn,cod_dev_dev, matricule_emp) 
values ('01/05/2016',2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,'V', select d.cod_dev_dev from table Devise d where d.lib_sigl_dev='AUS', 'emp_2' );
```

This picture may be let you understand what i want to do

[image]

can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into Cours_Change (DAT_JOUR_CCHN,mont_caba_cchn,mont_cabc_cchn,mont_cvba_cchn,mont_cvbc_cchn,cod_etat_cchn,cod_dev_dev, matricule_emp) 
select '01/05/2016',2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,'V', d.cod_dev_dev, 'emp_2' 
from Devise d where d.lib_sigl_dev='AUS'
```

Comment: no they are 8 columns ; 

the error is : missing left parenthesis at line 2 column 66

Comment: am not used to use this type of query ; so help me please :)

Comment: @khawlabelgacem:- There were few issues in your `select` query as well. I have updated my answer. You can try it.

Comment: Sir, I want just to recuperate the filed (cod_dev_dev) from table Devise not all fields ; you are puting select before all , so sorry but i see that not logic

Comment: @khawlabelgacem:- The other fields are constant and only the value `cod_dev_dev` will be picked from your table `Devise`. Basically the syntax to insert the record in table using the select is `INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2`

Comment: you re all right in what you said ,I understand and it works perfectly ,thank you Sir for helping me, am grateful :)